# difference between textView.becomeFirstResponder() and tapping on textView?

Tags: swift, keyboard, autolayout, uitextview, becomefirstresponder

I have an app page with multiple textfields and one textview.
The textview is similar to the message bar on chat apps.

When I tap the message textView box, the code I wrote adjusts the view according to the height of the keyboard.
But when I call messageTextView.becomeFirstResponder() instead, the view does not raise with the keyboard.

**Is there a difference between textView.becomeFirstResponder() and just tapping on the textView?**

- I have tested and can see that the code to raise the view is called in the debugger. it just don't execute on screen.
- I have also tested and see that becomeFirstResponder() is returning true

Comment: When you write `textView.becomeFirstResponder()` statement, that mean you are saying OS to open a keyboard for `textView`. And OS by default won't raise the `textView` position to avoid the keyboard overlap. So you have to write your own code to do that.

Comment: *"the code I wrote..."* -- difficult to help you without seeing the code you wrote. Is it in a keyboard will show notification handler? Did you add a tap gesture and you're calling it from there?